# TYPO3 upgrade 4.7.12 to 6.1.7 backend content view issue

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I successfully upgraded TYPO3 version 4.7.12 to 6.1.7, and also followed all steps for upgrading.
http://wiki.typo3.org/Upgrade

All functionality works fine in both side frontend and backend.

But the backend content view looks ugly, see attachment image.

Templating method: TemplaVoila

Please help me where I missed something.

[image]

Comment: Did you also upgrade the templavoila extension to the latest version?

Comment: OMG! OMG! That's the issue. TemplaVoila version 1.7.0 not compatible with TYPO3 6x. I upgraded templavoila to 1.8.0 and it's works for me. Thanks man lorenz.

Answer (score -1):

You should be aware, that TemplaVoila is not actively developed any more. It also is **not** 6.x compatible and will most likely not be fixed to become compatible.

From the looks of things I'd say either TemplaVoila or any other non compatible extension break your backend view. I'd suggest you disable all extensions that are not explicit 6.x compatible and try to enable your way back until you know which extension causes this, and TV is a good candidate for this.

As a possible replacement have a look at [fluidcontent](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fluidcontent) or write your own content elements via a simple extension.

Comment: Having said that there seems to be recent effords to fix some of the bugs through the community but I'd not count on this going on without a new major developer.

Comment: TemplaVoila not being compatible with TYPO3 6.x is an often heard myth but wrong. The current TER version is 6.x compatible and since many major sites use TemplaVoila, it will be kept compatible. However, it is true that it is not developed actively anymore, but if you are happy with the feature set and don't prefer other approaches (personally I prefer backend layouts and Grid Elements), you can stay with TemplaVoila.

Comment: Well I admid there were a few improvements since the last time I'd actually used it, but I follow the "news" around TV from time to time and while there are quite some bugs fixed I wouldn't go so far as to say it's fully compatible. As to "it will be kept compatible": it was only announced compatibility up until 6.2 and thats it. Yes thats the next LTS but I don't think thats enough to keep using it in a larger scale. Personally I don't support keeping an extension alive for the next LTS when it's not actively developed anymore.